# How can i do an if statement inside a repeater

Tags: c#, repeater, if-statement

`<asp:Repeater>` is driving me mad..

I need to do

```
<ItemTemplate>
    <% if (Container.DataItem("property") == "test") {%>
        I show this HTML
    <% } else { %>
        I show this other HTML
    <% } %>
</ItemTemplate>
```

But I can't for the life of me find any way to make that happen. Ternary isnt any good, because the amount of HTML is quite large, setting labels via a DataBind event is not very good either, as I'd have to have large blocks of HTML in the code-behind.

Surely there's a way to do this....

Comment: In your if statement you're using an assignment not an equality operator...is this a typo or how your actual code is?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could try creating a kind of ViewModel class, do the decision on your code-behind, and then be happy with your repeater, simply displaying the data that it is being given.

This is a way to separate logic from UI. You can then have a dumb-UI that simply displays data, without having to decide on what/how to show.

Comment: I think this is the crux of it, have the data totally clean before using a repeater. Life would be nice if you could use basic comparators in the repeater though.

Answer (score 22):

You could use server side visibility:

```
<ItemTemplate>
    <div runat="server" visible='<% (Container.DataItem("property") == "test") %>'>
        I show this HTML
    </div>
    <div runat="server" visible='<% (Container.DataItem("property") != "test") %>'>
        I show this other HTML
    </div>
</ItemTemplate>
```

Comment: this is a good solution if decision logic is going to be defined and used by frontenders that _does not_ have access to the underlying C# code.

Comment: The HTML will still be processed twice....  just becasue it has visible doesn't mean the compiler will skip that section of code

Answer (score 3):

You could do this with user controls:

```
<ItemTemplate>
    <uc:Content1 runat='server' id='content1' visible='<%# Container.DataItem("property") == "test" %>'/>
    <uc:Content2 runat='server' id='content2' visible='<%# Container.DataItem("property") != "test" %>'/>
</ItemTemplate>
```

Comment: Yeah, i thought of doing that, it would work, but a bit of a workaround. I've decided that repeater just isnt up for the task, and gone for a for/next loop, works a treat.

Answer (score 3):

Looks like I got this mixed up with the actual databinding

<strike>You can do it like so:</strike>

```
<asp:Repeater runat="server"> 
    <ItemTemplate>    
        <% if (((Product)Container.DataItem).Enabled) { %>
        buy it now!
        <% } else {%>
        come back later!
        <% } %>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

Comment: Container.dataitem only exists in the.. variable? markup, e.g. <%#

Comment: You're right, I thought I remembered doing something like this and now that I'm looking at my code it was logic on non-databinded values.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem and stumbled across this page. Thanks for the great answers, Gavin and Keltex got me on the right track but I had a bit of a tricky time getting this to work on my page.  Ultimately I was able to get it to work with this boolean, so I wanted to share for posterity:

**Show Checkbox if false**

```
<asp:CheckBox ID="chk_FollowUp" Visible='<%# (DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "FollowUp").ToString() == "False") %>' runat="server" />
```

**Show Flag img if true**

```
<asp:Image ID="img_FollowUp" AlternateText="Flagged" ImageUrl="Images/flag.gif" runat="server"
     Visible='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "FollowUp") %>' Height="30" Width="30" />
```

Comment: oh, and toggle between them with: `((CheckBox)sender).NamingContainer.FindControl("chk_FollowUp").Visible = false;((CheckBox)sender).NamingContainer.FindControl("img_FollowUp").Visible = true;`

Answer (score 0):

First You Have to Defind a Count variable in your Page.cs file

```
 <%if (Count == 0)
                         {
                             %>
                    <div style="background-color:#cfe9ed" class="wid_100 left special_text"><%# Eval("CompanyName") %></div>
                       <%}
                         else if (Count == TotalCount - 1)
                         {
                             %>
                        <div style="background-color:#f2f1aa" class="wid_100 left special_text"><%# Eval("CompanyName") %></div>
                        <%}
                         else
                         {
                              %>
                       <div class="wid_100 left special_text"><%# Eval("CompanyName") %></div><% } %>
                       <%Count++;  %>
```