# Trying to show or hide a DIV with vb.net code

Tags: html, asp.net, vb.net

Following example stated in

[How can i do an if statement inside a repeater](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1313725/how-can-i-do-an-if-statement-inside-a-repeater)

I'm trying to show or hide a div in html page that works with **vb.net code**, but no success.

```
<div runat="server" visible='<%# Container.DataItem.cod_dni = "10211721")%>' >
     Hello
</div>
```

Got error ID:
BC30944
Syntax error in cast operator; two arguments separated by comma are required.

Also I tried

```
<div runat="server" visible='<%# Container.DataItem("cod_dni") = "10211721")%>' >
     Hello
</div>
```

and got same error ID.

Comment: how about using Jquery

Comment: I guess you have a typo, at the end you have a bracket to much ... ")%>

Answer (score 1):

You probably just need to cast the `Container.DataItem`..  Assuming `cod_dni` is a string, try this:

```
<div runat="server" visible='<%# CStr(Container.DataItem("cod_dni")) = "10211721"%>' >
     Hello
</div>
```

Also,

there's an extra `)` in your statement at the end, so I took it out.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
visible='<%# IIf(Eval("cod_dni").ToString() = "10211721",true,false) %>'
```